# Points within "normal bounds" of a linestring in Python

Tags: python, shapely, linestring

I am working in Python (using Shapely). I have a list of Point(s) (the small circles in the image) and a LineString (the solid line with an arrow). I want to select only the points which are within the "normal bounds" of the LineString (the dashed lines show the normal bounds of the line - they intersect at 90 degress at the ends of the line).

I am using the below code to get the projection.

```
shapely_linestring.interpolate(shapely_linestring.project(shapely_point)
```

but if a point lies outside the "normal bounds", I still get a projection on the line at the nearest end. It does not give me a projection on the extended line, which I could have used.

Is there a better alternative to achieve identify such points?
[image]